# Error importing Rule Design Project in IBM ODM

Tags: ibm-odm

I am trying to import a rule design project into Eclipse, but Eclipse is importing the BOM, XOM and Rules folders as three different projects. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is typical for an IBM ODM implementation to consist of separate Eclipse projects for the BOM, XOM, and rules. Typically, the XOM project is a Java project, containing the Java classes that make up the execution object model; the BOM project is a 'Rule' project, containing the business object model; and the rules folder is a 'Rule' project, containing the business rules, rule flows, and other rule elements. All three projects work together to form a Decision Service or Rule App that can be deployed to the rule server.

So, I would say there are no problems with what you describe and that you are off to a good start!